# I have an excel where the C1 to C3 are merged, but in D1, D2, D3 there are values respectively. How can I calculate the sum for the merged cells

Tags: excel

I have an excel where C1 to C3 is merged, however, D1, D2 and D3 have values respectively. I need to calculate the sum of D1 to D3 against the merged cell from C1 to C3.

I tried a few of the formulas but did not help.

I have attached the snippet. Please help.

Comment: `=SUM(D1:D3)/C1` or whatever function you need to do. Merged cells have the value always on the top left cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Damian, it becomes tricky when you have a lot of values in the worksheet. I have attached a Snippet of the data I am working with, please review and help.

Comment: There is nothing attached on your post Jacob.